# Implement both TextOverflow.ellipsis and FittedBox

Tags: flutter

**Requirement:**
The text font size should reduce if there is long Text till a specific font size and after that should be ellipses(followed by ... and extra text should be hidden).

**Issue:**
these two feature works separately as in below code.

```
  FittedBox(
    child: Text("long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text", 
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0)),
  )

  Text("long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text", 
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  )
```

But if I combine these two it will ignore `TextOverflow.ellipsis`

```
  FittedBox(
    child: Text("long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text", 
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
  )
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!
This issue can be resolved using [AutoSizeText](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/auto_size_text#autosizetext), which will do both reduce font size and overflow ellipsis.

**Example:**

```
AutoSizeText(
  "A really long String",
  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
  minFontSize: 8.0,
  maxLines: 1,
  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
)
```